# Atom \K alternative when replacing text

Tags: regex, atom-editor

My use case is the following: I have a document that is 86,000 lines long. It has 5851 occurrences of the pipe symbol. I need to change every 5th occurrence from being just the pipe `|` to now being `]|`.

I have finally found the right regex `(?:(\d*|\D)*(\|)){9}\K` for my use case. I know this because I built it in this example at [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/qX1bH9/60). What it does is that it selects ONLY the *nth* pipe and allows me to interact with just that pipe.

If you increment/decrement the number in braces, it moves accordingly. Great. All hail.

However, `atom.io` (my editor) calls `\K` an invalid escape. What is the preferred regex for atom, please? Or even, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You could use the whole match in the replacement `^(?:[^|]*\|){3}[^|]*\|` https://regex101.com/r/UiEmPD/1 Or capture the part before the pipe in a group and match the last pipe if you want to replace it with something else https://regex101.com/r/c55dlx/1

Comment: Use a capturing group and the backreference, https://regex101.com/r/zvaJzN/1

Comment: OMG We are so close!! It's almost working.My document is 86,000 lines long and every 6th pipe needs to change from just | to ]|. These don't take that into account (because I neglected to say that).

Comment: I have now edited the original question. My apologies. I assumed I could work backwards from your answer.  But that is exactly what it was: working backwards!

Comment: So, to replace the 5th pipe, you use `^((?:[^|\r\n]*\|){4}[^|\r\n]*)\|` and replace with `$1]|`. Or with `\1]|`. Does it work? See https://regex101.com/r/Azx3vT/1

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   ok please add that as an answer and I will mark it!!!

Comment: You're a REGEX MASTER

Comment: It certainly helped me with my use-case and seems new. Believe me I searched (if you type \K into my Firefox-Duck combo you get settings and not search results so it wasn’t easy.). Credit where credit is due. I would like to mark it as answered and quite well at that. FWIW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point here is that `\K` is an operator that just omits the text matched so far from the current match memory buffer. You may read more about `\K` in [*Keep The Text Matched So Far out of The Overall Regex Match*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html).

When you need to *replace* something that is immediately preceded with some other string or text, you may simply use a [*capturing group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and a [*backreference*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html).

You may use

**Find What**: `^((?:[^|\r\n]*\|){4}[^|\r\n]*)\|` 
**Replace With**: `\1]|`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Azx3vT/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `((?:[^|\r\n]*\|){4}[^|\r\n]*)` - Capturing group 1 (referred to with `\1` from the replacement pattern):

  - `(?:[^|\r\n]*\|){4}` - four occurrences of

    - `[^|\r\n]*` - 0+ chars other than `|`, CR and LF (CR and LF are necessary so as not to overflow on the next lines)
    - `\|` - a pipe char (it is special in regex, hence, it is escaped)
  - `[^|\r\n]*` - 0+ chars other than `|`, CR and LF
- `\|` - a pipe that will be matched, consumed, and replaced with the replacement pattern.